# How can I customize the UI of alert messages in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, dialog, coronasdk

I am working on game in which I want to display alert message on mobile screen for selecting YES or NO. But I have only able to find native.alert in CoronaSDK

```
local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", "Dream. Build. Ship.", { "OK", "Learn More" } )
```

Is there any way to show dialog like Angry birds and other games have? Or any kind way create a self colorful dialog boxes in corona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using alert views. To achieve this you must create your custom popup view with images and buttons. I recommend you to take a look at the `storyboard.showOverlay` ([link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/showOverlay.html)) if you are using [storyboards](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html) in your project.

Comment: @Nomi If you need any help, tips or guidelines on how to implement this, feel free to ask.